# How to get the latitude and longitude in this code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i am using google map API ,user search their area means i want to get the latitude and logidute and stored in my database, i don't know how to do ,i am new in google map integrating please help me some one

```js
      // This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
      // for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
      // the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
      // selected.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location
          });
          marker.setVisible(true);

          document.getElementById('place-name').textContent = place.name;
          document.getElementById('place-id').textContent = place.place_id;
          document.getElementById('place-address').textContent =
              place.formatted_address;
          infowindow.setContent(document.getElementById('infowindow-content'));
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCW8mAAfcRRb4hrB33AWG_Mk71ZtORjOAo&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) you can use the Google Maps Geocoding API and query using an address and the api will respond with the geocoding (including latitude and longitude) for that address. For example the following request,

```
curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

, will repsond with

```
{
...    
"geometry" : {
   "location" : {
     "lat" : 37.4223664,
     "lng" : -122.084406
    },
    ...
},
...
}
```

You can find a detailed example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes).